# How do I get username and appname for file path

Tags: c++, winapi

How am I able to define a path like "C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/<APPNAME>", for different username and app? How do I set this to automatically get the user and the appname? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) to get the full path of App Local:

```
...
#include <KnownFolders.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
...
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, KF_FLAG_SIMPLE_IDLIST, NULL, &path); // NULL for current user
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the username:

```
char username[MAX_PATH];
DWORD size = MAX_PATH;
GetUserName(username,&size);
```

To get the appname(Executable File Name without ".exe"):

```
char appname[MAX_PATH];
char buffer[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(NULL, appname,MAX_PATH); //get the string: "PATH\\appname.exe"
char *szExe = NULL;
//Remove prefix
GetFullPathName(appname, MAX_PATH, buffer, &szExe);
//Remove suffix
strncpy_s(appname, szExe, strlen(szExe) - strlen(".exe"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Local AppData path for a given user, use `SHGetFolderPath()` specifying `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`, or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` specifying `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`. Both take an optional user token for the desired user account to query. If you don't provide a token, the user associated with the calling thread is used.